# nested loop for retrieving data from an API in Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a file JSON and I would like to retrieve the datas for the fields `label` and `svm`.

Here is the file [JSON](https://jsonblob.com/944380858471825408). The fields `label` and `svm` are into PORTFOLIO > REGROUPEMENT > ELEMENT

[img(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq6cv.png)

I have tried to display the datas via the GoogleChrome console.

```
getTitles(mode: PortfolioModeEnum): void {
    this.portfolioValue = 0;
    this.lines = [];
 
    this.service.getPortfolios(mode).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe((res: any) => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
        console.log("Test => " + res.REGROUPEMENT[0].ELEMENT[0]);
   }
        
    });
  }
```

I have an error message:

**core.mjs:6484 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')**

[img(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UMnN.png)

I don't know how to retrieve my data on a nested loop? I want to retrieve `LABEL` and `SVM`, please.

**portfolio.response.ts**

```
export interface PortfolioResponse extends ApiResponse {
    PORTFOLIO: {
        VALPTF: number;
        DETAILS: {
            ACCOUNTLAB: string;
            ACCOUNTTYPE: string;
            LABEL: string;
            ACCOUNTPHYSICAL: string;
        };
        REGROUPEMENT: InstrumentRegroupement[];
    }
}
 
export interface InstrumentRegroupement {
    TYPEVALUE: number;
    ASSETCATLABEL: string;
    CURRENCY: string;
    AMOUNT: number;
    PERCENTAGE: number;
    ELEMENT: {
        LABEL: string;
        STOCK: string;
        SVM: number;
        COUPONNUMBER: number;
        ISINCODE: string;
        MARKETPLACE: string;
        TYPEVALUE: number;
        ASSETCATLABEL: string;
        INSTRCURRENCY: string;
        AVERAGEDPRICE: number;
        QUANTITY: number;
        LASTPRICE: number;
        CURRENCYVALO: string;
        PRICEVARIATION: number;
        CAPITALGAINLOSS: number;
        ACCRUEDINTERESTS: number;
        VALORIZATION: number;
        VALORIZATIONEUR: number;
        DIFFER: number;
        DIFFEREUR: number;
        PERCENTAGE: number;
        BLOCKCATEGORY: string;
        BLOCKQUANTITY: number;
        AVALLOWED: string;
        PLACECODE: number;
        PLACELABEL: string;
        SECURITYPRICEVARIATIONPRC: number;
        SECURITYPRICEVARIATIONNOM: number;
        INITIALPURCHASEDATE: string;
        NOTATION: string;
        NBRORDRENOTE: number;
        PERFACHAT: number;
        REGROUP: number;
    }[];
 
    sort: { by: PortfolioSortEnum, dir: '' | 'asc' | 'desc' };
    showLine: boolean;
}
```

**EDIT**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z18pt.png)

**EDIT 2**

TS

```
getTitles(mode: PortfolioModeEnum): void {
    this.portfolioValue = 0;
    this.lines = [];
 
    this.service.getPortfolios(mode).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe((res: any) => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
        const data = res.PORTFOLIO.REGROUPEMENT.map((regroupment) => {
          return regroupment.ELEMENT.map((element) => ({
            label: element.LABEL,
            svm: element.SVM,
          }));
        }).flat();

   }
        
    });
  }
```

HTML

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does the console.log(res) return?

Comment: @Misha Mashina: I edited my first message. I retrieve several arrays...

Comment: Ah so you have 'PORTFOLIO' at the top-level: res.PORTFOLIO.REGROUPEMENT[0].ELEMENT[0]

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the expected result?

Comment: @Misha Mashina: Ok, but how do you just display the `label`, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply need a list of the `label` and `svm` fields without needing details of the rest of the hierarchy, you could use `array.map()` to exact the keys you need at each level, then use `array.flat()` to flatten the structure.

```
const data = res.PORTFOLIO.REGROUPEMENT.map((regroupment) => {
  return regroupment.ELEMENT.map((element) => ({
    label: element.LABEL,
    svm: element.SVM,
  }));
}).flat();
```

Comment: Thank you, how to display the data label into my html, please? I have tried `{{ line.label }} `, but I have an error message: `Error TS2339: Property 'LABEL' does not exist on type 'InstrumentRegroupement'.`; I edited my first message concerning the method.

Comment: I think you would just need to replace `const data` from my snippet with `this.lines` so that the mapped/flattened data is saved in the variable you're rendering in the HTML